# Can I use different weights and bias for each of the clients in tensorflow federated?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I want to know if it is possible to use different weights and bias for each of the clients in tensorflow_federated.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TensorFlow Federated supports client having their own model parameters.

The implementation of Federated Averaging in [`tff.learning.build_federated_averaing_process`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process) starts with a globally shared model which is [`tff.federated_broadcast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_broadcast) to each client (at this point each client has the *same* model weights and biases). Then each client trains on its own *local data*, resulting in each client having *different* weights and biases. Finally, only the weights are recombined into a shared global model using [`tff.federated_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_mean).

In this case, the computation takes the global model as input and outputs a new global model, keeping the individual client weights and biased contained within the simulation. However the simulation can be rewritten for the individual models.

Something like:

```py
MODEL_WEIGHTS_TYPE = ...  # a nested structure of tensors of the model weights
DATASET_TYPE = ... # a tff.SequenceType

@tff.tf_computation(MODEL_WEIGHTS_TYPE, DATASET_TYPE)
def local_train(model_weights, dataset):
   # do local training
   return new_model_weights

# Simulate 3 clients
client_model_weights = [w_a, w_b, w_c]
client_training_data = [d_a, d_b, d_c]

client_model_weights = tff.federated_map(
   local_train, (client_model_weights, client_training_data))

# client_model_weights[0] == the new, different weights for client 'A'
```

Comment: Can u please help in understanding how to define MODEL_WEIGHTS_TYPE and DATASET_TYPE for the example of simulation of 3 client. It will be of great help for me